# How to substract Time from column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm Trying to develop GPS Application , that have Stop/ Idling Report

so to get Duration of Stop each Vehicle in certain Area

I got This Query

```
SELECT MAX(time) - MIN(time) AS duration FROM tcm_packet
WHERE latitude ='-6.916202' AND longitude = '107.599276'
```

but it's only show 
    -17
not exactly hour and minute and second time ... even I use TIME() its show 17 second .. should be 17 hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i think i get it ... use TIMEDIFF()

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(MAX(time),MIN(time)) AS duration FROM tcm_packet
WHERE latitude ='-6.916202' AND longitude = '107.599276';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Refer the link:-**

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

> ```
> SELECT TIMEDIFF(MAX(time),MIN(time)) AS duration FROM tcm_packet
> WHERE latitude ='-6.916202' AND longitude = '107.599276';
> ```